# Ruby On Rails Mysql Access Denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, access-denied, mysql2

Im trying to excute the following command on a new rails project on my Ubuntu Server.

```
rails g scaffold User email:string username:string
```

but Im receiving the following error:

```
"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql2::Error)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/rails/membershipServices/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have tried accessing mysql thru my server with the credentials provided in database.yml and I can login just fine. But for some reason I can't do it via Ruby on Rails command. My database.yml is:

```
  # MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
# 
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: membershipServices_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ******
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: membershipServices_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ******
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: membershipServices_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ******
  host: localhost
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Again I verified that username and password provided was correct by logging into mysql via terminal on my server. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some more research on this website and was able to try different things. The only thing that helped me was renaming the username to root1 root2 and root3 to verify which environment it was using. After doing so I verified Development was being used. I added `Host: localhost` to my Development connection information and that did the trick.